# Counting number of words between punctuation characters in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, package, text-analysis

I want to use Python to count the numbers of words that occur between certain punctuation characters in a block of text input. For example, such an analysis of everything written up to this point might be represented as:

[23, 2, 14]

...because the first sentence, which has no punctuation except the period at the end, has 23 words, the "For example" phrase that comes next has two, and the rest, ending with the colon, has 14.

This probably wouldn't be too hard to make, but (to go along with the "don't reinvent the wheel" philosophy that seems especially Pythonic) is there anything already out there that would be especially suitable for the task?

Comment: Also, have any real example of the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I have tried a few casual web searches (which show a lot of parsers for word frequency counts, etc.); perhaps it is trivial enough that writing the bones of it myself won't be much trouble after all. It never hurts to ask as a non-expert, though. 

As for the problem, it's more of an experiment. This would be just a small component of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
punctuation_i_care_about="?.!"
split_by_punc =  re.split("[%s]"%punctuation_i_care_about, some_big_block_of_text)
words_by_puct = [len(x.split()) for x in split_by_punc]
```

Comment: You forgot a comma in your "punctuation_i_care_about". As it stands it won't output what the op is looking for.

Comment: Joran's answer = case in point on the trivial part, @geekazoid :-) Python is amazing.

Answer (score 4):

Joran beat me to it, but I'll add my approach:

```
from string import punctuation
import re

s = 'I want to use Python to count the numbers of words that occur between certain punctuation characters in a block of text input. For example, such an analysis of everything written up to this point might be represented as'

gen = (x.split() for x in re.split('[' + punctuation + ']',s))

list(map(len,gen))
Out[32]: [23, 2, 14]
```

(I love `map`)

Comment: I love functional programming in general ;)